# Balanced demodulator

Tags: modulation, demodulation

I came upon this expression "Balanced demodulator" while reading about signal modulation, but didn't find anything that explain what is a balanced demodulator, can anyone explain this or give me any reference that helps me understand what is a balanced demodulator?

Comment: Vast number of hits with a Google search. Question should be closed - insufficient research.

Comment: @LeonHeller Try actually *looking for an explanation*. Sure, there are many results, but they are mostly datasheets, application notes and product catalogs, which take you knowing what "balanced" refers to in this context for granted. There are no preceding questions about this on ee.se. Maybe we shouldn't just show the door to OP for not writing a superb question, for once. Don't forget that answering this would be helpful to other people as well.

Comment: I'm with @LeonHeller, I figured it out from the first paragraph of the first hit from entering "balanced demodulator" into Google.

Comment: When I have a question, the first thing i do is ask google, i wouldn't have posted my question if i have found anything useful on google, and as jms said most of the results are datasheets that doesn't explain the term itself, which i don't think it's used that much, as i didn't find any reference to it other than a couple datasheet, and if you think you found the answer i only asked for a link, so you could have posted the link that you found on google which might have helped me and might help others.

Comment: You asked for a link. Link-only answers are no good here and would be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To clarify the terminology:

- A modulator is a circuit that varies some property (frequency/phase, amplitude or some combination of thereof) of a signal (the carrier) according to another signal (the baseband).
- A demodulator reverses the action of the modulator, yielding the baseband from a modulated carrier.  Often a demodulator requires the unmodulated carrier as well, which is typically generated within a radio receiver by the *local oscillator* or LO.
- A frequency mixer is a fundamental building block of modulators, demodulators and many other circuits. It combines two waveforms into the product of the two, as in it multiplies one signal by the other. This is useful, because such multiplication will shift every frequency component in one signal to sum and difference frequencies determined by the frequency content of the other signal.

  For example, mixing a 1 MHz carrier with a 10 kHz tone will produce a signal ([specifically AM-DSSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-sideband_suppressed-carrier_transmission)) that contains both the sum of the frequencies of the two inputs (1.01 MHz) and the difference (0.99 MHz), but ideally no original 10 kHz or 1 MHz components. This operation is known as *upconversion*.

  A frequency mixer can also be used as part of a demodulator. For example, mixing a modulated carrier that contains a 1.01 MHz and a 0.99 MHz tone with a 1 MHz tone will produce an output with two sum frequencies (2.01 MHz and 1.99 MHz) and, as both 1.01 MHz and 0.99 MHz map to the same difference frequency when mixed with 1 MHz, a single 10 kHz difference frequency. Low pass filtering the mixer output to remove the high frequency components would yield the original 10 kHz baseband signal. This operation is known as *downconversion*.

Given that both modulators and demodulators are often just mixers combined with filters, and that modulators and demodulators are in many cases be very similar circuits, the three terms are often (quite confusingly) used interchangeably. What people mean by *balanced demodulator* is really either *demodulator which uses a balanced mixer* or actually just *(single or double) balanced mixer*.

---

#### What is a balanced mixer:

As briefly mentioned above, an ideal frequency mixer does not allow the frequency content found in the two inputs to pass unaltered to the mixed output, only the sum and difference frequencies of every input component. However, it may be desirable to allow significant frequency content from one or both inputs to pass directly trough to the output, as a tradeoff of otherwise better performance and/or lower cost.

- A *double balanced* mixer attempts to block the frequency content of both inputs from passing directly to the output, only allowing the sum and difference frequencies trough. The classic [ring modulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_modulator) and [Gilbert cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_cell) are examples of this type.
- A *single balanced* mixer allows frequency components from one of the two inputs to pass directly trough, but blocks the frequency content from the other input.
- An *unbalanced* mixer allows both to pass trough, so that the output contains both inputs a significant level in addition to the mixing products (and any harmonics etc.)

The inputs bleeding trough to the outputs in an unbalanced mixer is caused by the mixer effectively adding a DC offset to the input signals. *Balanced* refers to the *DC balance*, or lack of a DC bias acting on the inputs, in a balanced mixer.
For example, plain amplitude modulation is done with effectively a single balanced mixer: The carrier can swing both positive or negative, but the baseband input is DC biased so that it never swings negative, thus never multiplying the carrier by a negative value. As a result, the carrier is still present at the output in addition to the sum and difference frequencies.

Comment: You don't actually explain the term "balanced demodulator".

Comment: @LeonHeller Because I'm currently writing it. Thanks for the encouragement.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a synchronous demodulator on silicon. Why not? Used a PLL to track the incoming phase and frequency. The PLL ran at 4X incoming carrier, ensuring a 4-phase JohnsonCounter provided precise 0/90/180/270.

These phases 0/180 and 90/270 drove the standard BarryGilbert double-balanced mixer(s). For excellent balanced demodulator recovery of the AM carrier, I only needed 0/180 phases.

What is balanced? Both the RF injection and the LO injection are balanced, and your outputs (+ and -) are ideally just Sum and Difference. Sum and Diff appear in both the +out and the -out. You get to chose how to combine them, or ignore the complement.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6cQqW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Using 4-way subdivision will create a comb filter that will detect odd harmonics of the intended capture frequency as though they were signals of that frequency.  Using 6-way subdivision will not only eliminate even harmonics but also all multiple-of-three harmonics.